# New WireGuard private key begins 'WEAK' - is this a warning?

Tags: linux, security, wireguard

I generated a WireGuard key in a virtual machine using the standard procedure `wg genkey | tee privatekey | wg pubkey > publickey`. The VM is running via KVM with virtio RNG backed by `/dev/urandom`.

The private key that was generated looks like this:

`WEAKqv5b*****************************SS5w2M=` *(Asterisks added by me, the censored characters look like normal randomness)*

Is there a special meaning to a key that begins `WEAK`? Or is this just a case of humans finding patterns in randomness?

I generated a new key out an abundance of caution, and it does not exhibit this pattern.

Comment: I'd say you had 1/2^21 chance of generating a key starting with `WEAK`.

Answer (score 3):

That's a funny coincidence, but WireGuard isn't trying to tell you anything -- it just reads 32 bytes from /dev/urandom, and uses whatever comes out as the key (after a tiny bit manipulation to make it ready for Curve25519). In this case, the first 3 bytes, when base64 encoded, happened to spell WEAK.